# Extra Printing of Chars in 2D Char Array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print out each element of a 2d char arrray in turn using this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
char positions[3][3] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G', 'H', 'I'};
    int main(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                printf("%s \n", &positions[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But the output is:

```
ABCDEFGHI 
BCDEFGHI 
CDEFGHI 
DEFGHI 
EFGHI 
FGHI 
GHI 
HI 
I
```

Instead of:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
```

And I can't work out how to fix it. I've looked around and haven't been able to find any answers to this specfic issue. Any advice would be great. Thank you.

Comment: As an alternative to the answers, a correct way to print out a single character is `printf("%.1s\n", &positions[i][j]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your printf does take %s which forces the char array to be converted to a string starting from the first entry.
Try running

```
printf("%c \n", positions[i][j]);
```

to print out characters. And see what happens ;)

greetings

Comment: VS code says %c expects type int argument and tells me to change it to %s otherwiae it just prints out blank lines

Comment: @SOLSD You must drop the `&` from `&positions[i][j]` when it is used as the corresponding argument to the `%c`.

Answer (score 2):

There were a couple of things you did wrong.

1. You did not create a proper 2D array. You did create a 2D array, but you formatted it so that it looked like a 1D array (As seen in your code). This does compile however you don't want to be using this style.
2. You made it print the elements using `%s` which is meant for strings, not chars, you would use `%c` for that.

Everything else checks out though! The below code is how you could properly declare a 2D array:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // The last square bracket shows how many elements each
    // Array can hold
    char positions[3][3] = {
        {'A', 'B', 'C'},
        {'D', 'E', 'F'},
        {'G', 'H', 'I'}
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%c\n", positions[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: I count two sets of brackets, so 2d.

Comment: @stark Yeah, it wouldn't work that way, the first set of brackets specifies how many "rows" you'd like to have, while the second set specifies how many elements each row will hold.

Comment: The OP has defined and initialized a valid 2D array (certainly `char positions[3][3]` is *not* a 3D array definition). The only issue with the original code was the inappropriate use of `%s` in `printf`.

Comment: Oh wait, no you were right, forgot about that! Let me fix my answer.

Comment: Again, there is nothing wrong with the initialization `char positions[3][3] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'};`. It may be considered bad style but *not* wrong as far as the C language is concerned. The initialization is equivalent to `char positions[3][3] = {{'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E', 'F'}, {'G', 'H', 'I'}};`.